# xml to json using gson using java or solution to single element array issue in json

Tags: xml, json

I am working on a REST service which supports xml and json. For this we are using JIBX and using jibx mapping to define xml structutre out of value objects. this service, i need to extend it to support json also. The challenge i have is, service response structure and xml element nodes are defined in jibx binding. but to generate json with same names, i can only pass xml generated by jibx; not the value object. i tried couple of xml to json options like jackson, json.XML and etc... but i am seeing an issue with all of these approaches when i have a list with single element in it. the generated json response is not giving an array like structure if the List having a single item.

Following are options i want to explore:
a. is there a way i can convert xml string to json using Gson
b. is there a way to generate json using JIBX itself
c. are there any other json solutions which address issue with single element array and also allows to convert xml to json

really appriciate your response on this